# renaming the filename with regex in python using re

Tags: python, bash, sed

I have a folder which contains multiple files with a below filename as one example and I have multiple different such

```
_EGAZ00001018697_2014_ICGC_130906_D81P8DQ1_0153_C2704ACXX.nopd.AOCS_001_ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam
```

Now I want to rename then using only by `ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam` will change according to the file in the path. The string corresponding to the name *.rsem.bam should be the one separated by "_". So for all the files in the directory should be replaced accordingly by this. I am thinking to use the regular expression so I came up with the below pattern

```
pat=r'_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.\w+)'
```

This separates out my filename as desired and I can rename the filenames with by using a global variable where I take only `pat[4]`. I wanted to use python since I want to learn it as of now to make small changes as file renaming and so on and later with time convert my workflows in python. I am unable to do it. How should I make this work in python? Also am in a fix what should have been the corresponding bash regex since this one is a pretty big filename and my encounter with such is very new. Below was my code not to change directly but to understand if it works but how should I get it work if I want to rename them.

```
import re
import os
_src = "path/bam/test/"
_ext = ".rsem.bam"
endsWithNumber = re.compile(r'_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.\w+)'+(re.escape(_ext))+'$')
print(endsWithNumber)
for filename in os.listdir(_src):
    m = endsWithNumber.search(filename)
    print(m)
```

I would appreciate both in python and bash, however, I would prefer python for my own understanding and future learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
import re
import os
_src = "path/bam/test/"
new_s = [re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.rsem\.bam", filename) for filename in os.listdir(_src)]
for first, second in zip(os.listdir(_src), new_s):
    if second is not None:
         os.rename(first, second.group(0))
```

Comment: I could not get this one done. Do not we need to loop before like `for filename in os.listdir(_src):`?  and I am getting a syntax error even if I simply write this putting _src as the path.

Comment: @vchris_ngs Please try now with the code above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I am getting the below error,`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testRname.py", line 4, in <module>
    new_s = [re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.rsem\.bam", filename).group(0) for filename in os.listdir(_src)]
  File "testRname.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    new_s = [re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.rsem\.bam", filename).group(0) for filename in os.listdir(_src)]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @vchris_ngs Please try now. I forgot to account for the fact that some filenames in the directory will not match the pattern specified.

Comment: should not it rename the files in the dir(_src), the prints are working but the filenames are not changing. Sorry, my python knowledge is very limited. `iimport re
import os
_src = "/marconi_scratch/userexternal/vdas0000/ICGC/data/EGA.Bam/test/"
new_s = [re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.rsem\.bam", filename) for filename in os.listdir(_src)]
print(new_s)
final_data = [i.group(0) for i in new_s if i is not None]
print(final_data)` output : is in form of list, so how will that rename the files in the directory?

Comment: output `[None, None, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(72, 100), match='ICGCDBDE20130916036.rsem.bam'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(72, 100), match='ICGCDBDE20130916016.rsem.bam'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(72, 100), match='ICGCDBDE20130916004.rsem.bam'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(72, 100), match='ICGCDBDE20130916035.rsem.bam'>]
['ICGCDBDE20130916036.rsem.bam', 'ICGCDBDE20130916016.rsem.bam', 'ICGCDBDE20130916004.rsem.bam', 'ICGCDBDE20130916035.rsem.bam']`

Comment: @vchris_ngs My apologizes! I misread your question. The code I posted now should rename the files for you if a match is found. Please let me know how it works.

Comment: thanks now its working, my mistake, I should have been more precise. works now

Comment: @vchris_ngs glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rpartition` which will separate out the part you want from the rest in to a three part tuple.

Given:

```
>>> fn
'_EGAZ00001018697_2014_ICGC_130906_D81P8DQ1_0153_C2704ACXX.nopd.AOCS_001_ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam'
```

You can do:

```
>>> fn.rpartition('_')
('_EGAZ00001018697_2014_ICGC_130906_D81P8DQ1_0153_C2704ACXX.nopd.AOCS_001', '_', 'ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam')
```

Then:

```
>>> _,sep,new_name=fn.rpartition('_')
>>> new_name
'ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam'
```

If you want to use a regex:

```
>>> re.search(r'_([^_]+$)', fn).group(1)
'ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam'
```

As a practical matter, you would test to see if there was a match before using group(1):

```
>>> m=re.search(r'_([^_]+$)', fn)
>>> new_name = m.group(1) if m else fn
```

For `sed` you can do:

```
$ echo "$fn" | sed -E 's/.*_([^_]*)$/\1/'
ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam
```

Or in Bash, same regex:

```
$ [[ $fn =~ _([^_]*)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
ICGCDBDE20130916001.rsem.bam
```

Answer (score 1):

Too much work.

```
newname = oldname.rsplit('_', 1)[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os  
fname = 'YOUR_FILENAME.avi'
fname1 = fname.split('.')
fname2 = str(fname1[0]) + '.mp4'
os.rename('path to your source file' + str(fname), 'path to your destination file' + str(fname2))
fname = fname2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.